# Archiving fga_log$: sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.clean_audit_trail doesn't delete anything

Tags: oracle, audit

I am having a problem to archive and then delete portions of the `fga_log$` table.

Here's what a script basically does

```
insert into fga_log_archive
select 
  ...
from
  sys.fga_log$;


begin
   sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.set_last_archive_timestamp(
     audit_trail_type     => sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.audit_trail_fga_std,
     last_archive_time    => systimestamp
  );

  sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.clean_audit_trail(
   audit_trail_type        => sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.audit_trail_fga_std,
   use_last_arch_timestamp => true
  );
end;
/
```

The [documentation for dbms_audit_mgmt.clean_audit_trail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_audit_mgmt.htm#autoId9) says:

> This procedure deletes audit trail records. The `CLEAN_AUDIT_TRAIL` procedure is usually called after the `SET_LAST_ARCHIVE_TIMESTAMP` Procedure has been used to set the last archived timestamp for the audit records.

So, I have expected the records that were *archived* with the insert statement to be deleted
from the `fga_log$` table by the `clean_audit_trail` call. That's not the case however. Am I missing something?

**Edit**

The audit configuration parameters as selected with

```
select 
  substrb(parameter_name ,1,25) name, 
  substrb(parameter_value,1,20) value,
  substrb(audit_trail    ,1,20) trail
from
  dba_audit_mgmt_config_params
;
```

is

```
NAME                      VALUE                TRAIL
------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
DB AUDIT TABLESPACE       SYSAUX               STANDARD AUDIT TRAIL
DB AUDIT TABLESPACE       AUDIT_LOG_TABLESPACE FGA AUDIT TRAIL
AUDIT FILE MAX SIZE       10000                OS AUDIT TRAIL
AUDIT FILE MAX SIZE       10000                XML AUDIT TRAIL
AUDIT FILE MAX AGE        5                    OS AUDIT TRAIL
AUDIT FILE MAX AGE        5                    XML AUDIT TRAIL
DB AUDIT CLEAN BATCH SIZE 10000                STANDARD AUDIT TRAIL
DB AUDIT CLEAN BATCH SIZE 10000                FGA AUDIT TRAIL
OS FILE CLEAN BATCH SIZE  1000                 OS AUDIT TRAIL
OS FILE CLEAN BATCH SIZE  1000                 XML AUDIT TRAIL
DEFAULT CLEAN UP INTERVAL 999                  FGA AUDIT TRAIL
```

**Edit II**

`select * from v$version` returns

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Comment: I suppose `is_cleanup_initialized` returns true for that audit type? (I have no idea if that's even required or not.)

Comment: @mat: Yes, `sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.is_cleanup_initialized(sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.audit_trail_fga_std)` returns true.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of SELECT * FROM dba_audit_mgmt_config_params;. Thanks

Comment: @Phil: I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Rac? 11.2.0.3??

Comment: @Phil: It's not a RAC environment, the database version is *11.2.0.1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Mat* has pointed out, I hit **Bug 9164488** (`DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.CLEAN_AUDIT_TRAIL does not delete sys.aud$ and sys.fga_log$ tables [ID 9164488.8]`) which should be fixed in Release 11.2.0.2.

In the *meantime*, running on 11.2.0.1, I was able to circumvent the bug with a *purge job* in order to do the work. As soon as I ran

```
begin
  sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.create_purge_job (
     audit_trail_type           => sys.dbms_audit_mgmt.audit_trail_fga_std,
     audit_trail_purge_interval => 999,
     audit_trail_purge_name     =>'Purge_Test',
     use_last_arch_timestamp    => true
  );
end;
/
```

`clean_audit_trail` would do the work, as previously expected.